# Where are offline-editable Google Docs stored?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

When you choose to save a Google Docs file for editing offline it creates a file in your Google Drive folder. However, that file is just a URL to the online Drive. Do you know where actual file is stored?

Comment: There's the same question [posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797114/google-drive-offline-document-file-location) from a while back...

Comment: Thank you :) but I can't mark it as answer.

Comment: I've added it as an answer if you want to close the question by accepting it. It's not that I'm desperate for the points, you understand ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797114/google-drive-offline-document-file-location) was posted on Stack Overflow back in 2012.

In the accepted answer it says

> It turns out the offline documents are stored in the HTML5 FileSystem.
>
> I added a number of large images to a document with the Chrome
>   "Offline Docs" enabled and was able to see the FileSystem storage
>   directory grow appropriately.
>
> I then used the HTML5 FileSystem Explorer extension for Chrome to view
>   the file structure of an offline document and was able to confirm that
>   the images were, indeed being retrieved from the HTML5 FileSystem when
>   Chrome was offline.